# default URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

it seem that we need to specify a route for every page in webform routing

I want to use default route to a page called **cms.aspx** with parametr called **nameofurl** for each page **expect** default.aspx

sometimes I want to send the cms.aspx more then one parametrs,for example

mydomain.com/cms.apx?nameurl=somevalue

or

mydomain.com/cms.apx?nameurl=somevalue&order=6

I have this code but it isn't the solution since you have to tell the routing the name of the page

```
  routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "pageName/{nameofurl}",
        "~/cms.aspx")
```

I want something like this

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "?/{nameofurl }",
        "~/cms.aspx")
```

sometimes I want it to be like this

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SalesRoute",
    "?/{nameofurl}/{order}",
    "~/cms.aspx");
```

any idea how to Achieve that kind of routing without specify the name of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create routes like given below:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Route1","{nameofurl}","~/cms.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("Route2","{nameofurl}/{order}","~/cms.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("Route3","{nameofurl}/{order}/{abc}","~/cms.aspx")
```

The above routes will work if there are no other pages with 2 or 3 parameters. But if there is some other page which you want to route and which has 2 parameters to be passed, then you need to mention a hard-coded string before the parameters otherwise the new route will override the old route.

For Example:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Route4","{nameofurl}/{order}","~/products.aspx")
```

In the above case, Route4 will override Route 2. Thus, you need to define route something like below:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Route4","products/{nameofurl}/{order}","~/products.aspx")
```

You can find URL Routing related articles at following URLs:

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-part-2.html

Thanks & Regards,

Munjal